# Why double arrow for Scala and C# lambdas?

Tags: c#, scala, programming-languages

Does anyone know some background, why Scala and C# use double arrow (=>) for lambdas instead of single arrow (->)?

Single arrow is more common in literature, is used in Haskell, O'Caml, F#, Groovy etc. and IMO it also looks nicer :)

Comment: Standard ML also uses `=>`.

Comment: Perhaps (in C# at least) to avoid confusion with the C++ pointer member invocation operator with the same symbol.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pizza, which was sort of a predecessor for Scala had -> in function types. I remember that C++ programmers were baffled by this choice of symbol. That's the primary reason why Scala chose => AFAIRC. It seems the C# guys went through the same reasoning.

Comment: Well, the C# guys couldn't use the `->` arrow because it means the same thing in C# that it does in C++. Since Pizza and Scala don't have the pointer dereference operator, it's not quite the same reasoning.

Comment: This should be the correct answer to at least half of the question.

Answer (score 21):

In C#,
maybe because `->` operator is already used in case of unsafe code [(LINK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8bz4d5h.aspx)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the influence of other functional languages had a larger part to play in Scala's design. C# is definitely not the reason, the fact that C# has the => syntax as well could just as easily have the same reasoning.

Answer (score 10):

In Scala, there is also the "map arrow" that indicates a mapping from an item `a` to another `b`.  Using `=>` for lambdas frees up `->` for things like `Map(1 -> "One", 2 -> "Two")`, and as others have pointed out the `=>` is not unique to C# and Scala.

Comment: Of course, you could also reason that if they had used the `=>` map arrow from Perl, that would have freed-up the `->` arrow for lambdas.

Answer (score 4):

you might be interested to know that in Scala you can use the unicode equivalent for => as well as other arrows: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/More-unicode-alternatives-for-ASCII-operators-td2008146.html